# How can I resolve 'no module named' error in python virtual env?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I activated a python virtualenv and installed a package.

My code import the package, but the code isn't executed with import error.

My situation:

```
(myenv) [my_server]$ python3 my_code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
(myenv) [my_server]$ pip3 install pyMySQL
Requirement already satisfied: pyMySQL in /SOMEPATH/package/python-3.5.0-r2/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.10.0)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.2b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(myenv) [my_server]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
.
```

I'm working on a remote server, and the above problem occurs.

I think that some configuration should be set.. but I can't figure it out.

Any thought appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed a path.

```
(myenv) [my_server]$ pip3 install pyMySQL
Requirement already satisfied: pyMySQL in /SOMEPATH/package/python-3.5.0-r2/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.10.0)
```

Referring to the result of the above command,

```
export PYTHONPATH=/SOMEPATH/package/python-3.5.0-r2/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Then, my virtualenv found python packages well.